# How can I set an alias name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
IF RTRIM(@GLDD_LEDGER_CODE)= '00' 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @SYS_REM =GLMA_ACCT_NAME  
    FROM  GLAS_GL_MASTERS 
    WHERE    GLMA_COMP_CODE  = @COMP_CODE
     AND    GLMA_LDGR_CODE  = '00'
     AND    GLMA_DEPT_NO  = SUBSTRING(@GLDD_ACCT_CODE, 2, 2)
     AND    GLMA_ACCT_CODE  = SUBSTRING(@GLDD_ACCT_CODE, 4, 4)
     AND    GLMA_YEAR  = DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())
END

ELSE
BEGIN 
    SELECT @SYS_REM = A.COAD_PTY_FULL_NAME AS NAME
    FROM  GLAS_PTY_ADDRESS A,
         GLAS_SBLGR_MASTERS B 
    WHERE    A.COAD_COMP_CODE  = @COMP_CODE
     AND    A.COAD_COMP_CODE  = B.SLMA_COMP_CODE
     AND    A.COAD_ADDR_ID  = B.SLMA_ADDR_ID
     AND    B.SLMA_LDGRCTL_CODE  = @GLDD_LEDGER_CODE
     AND    B.SLMA_LDGRCTL_YEAR  = DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())
     AND    B.SLMA_STATUS  = 'A'
     AND    B.SLMA_ACNO  = @GLDD_ACCT_CODE      
END
```

How can I set alias name for both select statement for selecting the name?

Comment: Why do you want to set an alias for the field in the SELECT clause when the value is being captured in variable ` @SYS_REM` ?

Comment: bcoz i ve to set name in front end in asp.new

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set alias name for both
>   select statement for selecting the
>   name?

You can't because you are storing it in a variable.

Either use an OUTPUT parameter (if this code is in a stored procedure) or

SELECT @SYS_REM AS MyName

to return it as a result set